# UV unwrapping mesh with radial array modifier

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, uv

[image]

I have this floor mesh which was modeled using the array modifier w/ rotation to create an hexagonal shape. I started unwrapping and marked my seams (in red). The edges selected in ORANGE are the ones on which I do not want any seams, but they happen to be on opposite sides of the mesh. Therefore I need to align them (as if they were merged) but the weld and stitch commands are no good because they are on opposite sides of the mesh. How to superpose them precisely on top of each other so there are no visible seams, or at least how do I align these islands based on the selected edges without moving only the edges and distorting the map (I need the whole island to move along).

Comment: Do you want to stitch the opposite sides of the mesh? Why are you trying to do it this way?

Comment: because opposite sides of the mesh will actually be touching, this is an array, and I don't want any seam where they meet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Enable UV snap and change it to **Vertex**, then move one island till it snaps to one of the connecting vertices.

[image]

2. Select the connecting vertex and snap 2D cursor to its location using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> Shortcut and change Pivot Point to 2D Cursor

[image]

3. Select one UV island and rotate it till it snaps to the other side of second UV island.

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating only one section of the floor and unwrapping it first.  Texture it first.  Then duplicate it radially second.

You may want to create a frame of this radially symmetric image, save it as a pnc file, and use it a texture on an some other simpler mesh.

Comment: If not sure if I understand what you're saying properly, but this IS only one section that has been unwrapped. The array modifier is not applied. In fact if it was applied, I wouldn't have this problem at all but the whole point of my question is because I want to avoid to apply it. I'm not sure what you mean either by creating a "frame"? And I'm not familiar with PNC files, unless you meant PNG? In fact this is not radial symmetry, this is radial translation (or simply rotation). Could you elaborate on your solution?